# In Python, convert an array of bytes to integer

Tags: python-3.x

I am retrieving bytes of data from an IC2 device using the read_i2c_block_data function.  Within this block of data are signed 16-bit values that I want to display.  I am able to print out the value correctly using the following:

```
print ("PC12  : %d mW" % int.from_bytes((return_data[5],return_data[6]), byteorder='little', signed=True))
```

Though, I have been trying print out the value using the following, which doesn't work and I don't know why.  I am curious to why I can't get it to work.

```
print ("PC12  : %d mW" % int.from_bytes(return_data[5:6], byteorder='little', signed=True))
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  I thought I could specify the range in the from_bytes function.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What exactly happens, and how does that differ from what you expected to happen? What type is `return_data`?

Comment: The conversion was not correct and only converting just one of the bytes, but I couldn't figure out why.  vituat enlightened me to what was happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return_data[5:6]` returns an array consisting of a single element at index 5:

```
>>> return_data = b'\00\01\02\03\04\05\06'
>>> return_data[5:6]
b'\x05'
```

Since you want to convert a 16-bit integer, you need to use `return_data[5:7]`.

Comment: vitaut, brilliant.  That worked like a charm.  It appears I really didn't understand the indexing/range syntax.  With that, I was able to get the selection to work and fix a few other bugs I had.  Thanks!!!!